# Excel (VBA): Sum values in a column until value in other column is reached/matched

Tags: vba, excel, sum, multiple-columns

I would like to sum up the values in Column B until the value in Column A is matched. When it is, I want to skip to the next value in Column A, offset(0,1) and sum again until that value is reached, and so on
Whenever the value in Column A is reached I want to put all the cells used to aquire the value from Column A and put them in Column C (highlighting the interior with some color would work too)
When summing up the values it will always match exactly the value in A, so = and not >

I attached a screen from a portion of my table below.

e.g.: I wanna take the first value in Column A, 443.33, offset one to the right and start summing the values in that column until I have exactly 443.33. When I have it, I want to take the cells that where needed to create the desired sum (in that case only B2) and copy them to their adjacent cells in column C (in that case => C2).
Then I want to find the next value in Column A (66,144.90) and repeat.

I have tried to do this with Excel-Formulas and Excel-VBA. Unfortunately with no success.

Appreciate some help.
Thank you

[Screen from my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVt8Y.png)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZQEV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fill your needs. It tries to match the values, if thats not possible it'll continue with the next value. the required cells are highlighted with a color.

```
   Sub MatchValues()
Dim IndexA, IndexB, i, j, k As Integer
Dim ValueA, ValueB As Variant
Dim lrA, lrB As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Worksheets("Tabelle1")
lrA = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrB = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


For i = 1 To lrA
    If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
    ValueA = CDec(sht.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    ValueB = 0
        For j = i To lrB
            If IsNumeric(sht.Cells(j, 2).Value) Then
                ValueB = ValueB + CDec(sht.Cells(j, 2).Value)
            End If
            If ValueA = ValueB Then
                sht.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(j, 2)).Interior.ColorIndex = 33 + k
                sht.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 33 + k
                k = k + 1
                Exit For
            ElseIf ValueB > ValueA Then
                    MsgBox ("Error for Value in Row: " & i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. The code looks very promising. I get an error message though: runtime error '13': Type mismatch  
for the lines 'ValueB = ValueB + sht.Cells(j, 2).Value'  
I tried changing it to string, but still getting the error

Comment: Can you run this version, i added that it will only add numeric values.

Comment: Code is running now, but it only worked for the value where no sum was needed, i.e. only those where the adjacent value was the matching one.  So the 66,144.90 didn't work

Comment: Actually, it did work for the remainder of the table (not in screenshot), only that one didn't get highlighted. It seems that it's only working for a maximum of 2 cells in the sum.

Comment: So changed the Vars to the proper vartype. it should work better now, if there were any other error. the 66,144.90 value does not add up as you illustrated in your example, the value is higher. you can uncomment the msgbox and it will give you the row where it didnt work.

Comment: Does exactly as you say. It gives me the error in Row 5. However, the values do add up perfectly.

Comment: I inserted 'debug.print ValueB' after the Value = code and it sums up the values just fine. The sum end at the desired value of 66,144.90 but then resumes with the error message.

Comment: Ok, i recalculated it and it fits now, dont know what i did there. i pasted the values into my sheets and it work for me tho. Could be something wrong with your formating?

Comment: Ok, it is the formating, if you change it to currency it works fine, but just number formating like that it does not work. ill try to find the reason why

Comment: Try this version, it works fine now with the standard number format.

Comment: Gives me error: type mismatch at ValueA = cDec()  . But changing it to currency is fine for me, so I'll just use that. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using formulas rather than VBA.

You will use an additional two "working" columns.

The first working column C is a tracking column for the last value in column A. The formula for C5 is

```
=IF(A5<>"",A5,C4)
```

This checks to see if there is a new value in column A, uses it if there is, else uses the previous value in column A from the row above.

The second working column D keeps a running total of column B, restarted each time there is a value in column A

```
=IF(A5<>"",B5,D4+B5)
```

And then the numbers you want are in Column E

```
=IF(D5<=C5,B5,"")
```

[image: Example]